# sha1 to sha256 hash adjustment

Tags: encryption, hash, sha1, sha256

I have a statement ":

```
    $hash = strtoupper(sha1($_POST['orderID'] . $_POST['currency'] . 
    $_POST['amount'] . $_POST['PM'] . $_POST['ACCEPTANCE'] . 
    $_POST['STATUS'] . $_POST['CARDNO'] . $_POST['PAYID'] . 
    $_POST['NCERROR'] . $_POST['BRAND'] . 'Kerkkl01'));
```

statement is needed to  login and sent a payment request

This statement needs to be converted to a SHA-256, as my payment provider wants me to connect with SHA-256.

The sha1() is a normal php function, so my thought was to change the sha1() into sha256() and change the SHA-IN  parameter from 'Kerkkl01' to '543GropTeter01?!890' as a stronger/longer encryption phrase is needed.

But...no way this is working. So how do I change from a SHA-1  to a SHA-256 connection in the above given $hash ?

Comment: What do you mean "no way this is working?" In what way does it not work? What do you mean by "SHA-IN parameter?" In the code you've posed "Kerkkl01" is a salt. Are you certain that you are providing exactly the correct fields and correct salt (does the other side also use "543GropTeter01?!890" as its salt?) If you print out the result of the string you are passing to `sha256`, does it look correct?

Comment: Hello Rob when I change te word sh1 into sha2 or sha256 I got errors like "inknown function in line 546..." meaning that the it does not exist this whole function in php.  In the meantime I have found a solution which I will share here.